# How to use three streams in java 8 lambdas together?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a `class Country` that contains a `List<City>`, a `class City` contains a `List<Street>`, and a `class Street` contains a `class Human`with a unique ID. I can't understand where is my mistake. I know there are brackets missing somewhere, but I don't know where to put them.

```
Human finded = country.getCities()
                .stream()
                .map(cty-> cty.getStreets()
                        .stream()
                        .map(strt-> strt.getHumans()
                                .stream()
                                .filter(hmn-> hmn.getID().equals(wantedID))
                                        .findFirst()
                                        .orElse(null);
```

Comment: You're in the middle of two `map()` calls. You can add two closing parentheses, but then you'd be left with a `Stream<Stream<Human>>`. You might want to take a look at `Stream.flatMap()`.

Comment: Do you have any conditions, for example specific city or street names you want to apply, or do you just want every human in every street in every city in the country?

Comment: http://www.flatmapthatshit.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` turns a single element in a stream into a single other element.

It's useless here - you want to turn, say, a single element (a `City` instance) into any number of Street elements. Could be 0 (bit of a weird City), could be 20,000. Mapping a single City to a single Street isn't going to work.

Thus, you want `flatMap` instead, which turns a single element in a stream into any number (0, 1, or a million - whatever you like) of elements. Given that one element needs to be turned into X elements, you can't just "return an element" the way `map` works. Instead, you return a stream.

```
county.getCities().stream()
  .flatMap(c -> c.getStreets().stream())
  .forEach(System.out::println)
  ;
```

would print every street in all cities, one per line.